# Is Cat-v.org an official subsidiary website of Plan 9 from Bell Labs?

Tags: history, plan9

I was wondering, since it seems to be one of the only websites where I can *seemingly* legally download historic Unix documents.

Comment: Given that is says, prominently, ["unofficial homepage"](http://iwp9.cat-v.org/), that would be a "no"...

Comment: It does provide almost all of the information about plan9 or a link to it. The actual page has been removed but you can find a copy of what it used to be and updates at http://9p.io/

Answer (score 2):

cat-v.org was the personal website of Uriel before he passed away and not in any way officially affiliated with Bell Labs.